# Django: collectstatic raises OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: (ckeditor)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-16.04, django-staticfiles

Suddenly, I can't do `collectstatic`.

```
python manage.py collectstatic

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/jquery.init.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/django/maklerienv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/django/maklerienv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/django/maklerienv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/django/maklerienv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/django/maklerienv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 189, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/django/maklerienv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/home/django/maklerienv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 344, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
  File "/home/django/maklerienv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 294, in delete_file
    self.storage.delete(prefixed_path)
  File "/home/django/maklerienv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 299, in delete
    os.rmdir(name)
OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/django/makleri/static/ckeditor'
```

I tried to delete whole static folder and rerun `collectstatic` but it didn't help. Do you know how to make it work?

It works on my PC, this is a server.

Comment: Did you try to delete static dir with `-f` flag? Try `rm -rf static`.

Comment: I tried it now and the same error raises.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `collectstatic`. For me, the following helped:

> python3 manage.py collectstatic --clear

According to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/):

> --clear, -c
>
> Clear the existing files before trying to copy or link the original file.

The problem is that `self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage)` does not work on non-empty directories. `-rf` would help, but django's `collectstatic.py` does not use it.